# How to recover accidentally deleted /etc folder from ubuntu wsl2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

/etc folder was accidentally deleted in Ubuntu-20.04 WSL. I don't have a backup, but I do have ext4.vhdx in the LocalState path in Windows. Is it possible to restore from this ext4.vhdx? I need to recover /etc folder and get WSL running again. Please help.

Comment: The original rootfs is actually still on your drive under a hidden directory, so I *think* we should be able to get the original `/etc` files back at least.

Comment: "Is it possible to restore from this ext4.vhdx?" - No; Your files existed within a virtual HDD on a physical HDD.  FIle recovery software has no way to scan for the file, the physical file still exits, your virtual HDD. "I need to recover /etc folder and get WSL running again" - No; Just uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu and you will have a fresh WSL Ubuntu instance.

Comment: Raghu, I haven't forgotten about you.  Turned out to be a little more complicated (at least to do it as close to "right" as possible, IMHO) than I expected.  Ultimately, I *would* recommend that you back up your home directory from the instance and just reinstall, though.  It's likely easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

.vhdx is the virtual disk of your Ubuntu. It contains the filesystem. You've deleted the /etc directory from the file system, so you've deleted it from the virtual disk.

Just bite the bullet, delete the VM and create a new one.

Practically we all learned the importance of backups the hard way. It's just a human thing.

Answer (score 0):

As Peregrino69 mentioned, you won't be able to recover anything from `ext4.vhdx` since that's just the "live" filesystem in a virtual disk.  Once you deleted `/etc`, it was immediately gone from `ext4.vhdx`.

While I'm providing the instructions below if you *really* want to try, my personal advice would be similar to that of Peregrino69.  I'd start over.

However, I would at least back up your home directory (`tar cvzf home.tgz ~`) from your installation first.  That way you can copy it back into your new installation.

You can also do a `wsl --export Ubuntu backup.tar` to have a snapshot of the current instance in its entirety.

Once you have backed up, you can do `wsl --unregister <distroname>` (leaving the distroname for you to confirm since this is a destructive operation).

This will delete the *entire* instance and all files in the virtual filesystem.

You can then reinstall by simply running `ubuntu.exe` (or `ubuntu2004.exe`, depending on which Store version you installed).

##### What's "recoverable" (and what's not)

| What | Recoverable? |
| --- | --- |
| `/etc` as it existed after you first installed WSL/Ubuntu | Yes |
| Your default username/password that you set during the initial Ubuntu configuration stage | No, but can be easily recreated via `useradd` |
| Any configuration added to `/etc` by packages you installed manually | Maybe |
| Any configuration added to `/etc` by you manually or by the manual execution of a command (e.g. `useradd`) | No, these files will need to be recreated manually |

If you are okay with this ...

##### Create a snapshot/backup

Just to be "safe", I would recommend a backup of the WSL instance:

```
wsl --export <distroName> <filename.tar>
```

##### Starting WSL with no `/etc`

The good news is that running the `wsl` command and starting Ubuntu with no `/etc` still, at least, results in running in a degraded state.  Since there's no `/etc/passwd`, you'll be "UID/GID 0", not even `root`.  You'll also be launched into `dash` by default.  So let's start off by at least getting a more functional shell by launched `bash`.

Since your prompt is going to be something like:

```
I have no name!@Host:dir>
```

You might want to shorten it with `PS1='$(pwd)> '`.  This is completely optional of course, but I found it useful for making things more readable.

##### Recovering the initial `/etc/` from the WSL/Ubuntu rootfs image

Our first goal is to restore `/etc` to the state that it existed after your initial install.  To do that, we'll use the rootfs image that comes with the Ubuntu Appx package that you installed from the Microsoft Store.

First we need to find it.  Start by running:

```
package='"*Ubuntu*"'
powershell.exe -c "Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { \$_.Name -like $package }"
```

If only one result is returned, great.  If not, tweak the `package` variable to be more specific -- `'"*UbuntuonWindows*"'` or `'"*Ubuntu20.04onWindows*"'`.  Once you can run the command and only get one result ...

```
packageLocation=$(powershell.exe -c "(Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { \$_.Name -like $package })[0].InstallLocation" | tr -d "\r\n")
packageLocation=$(wslpath "$packageLocation")
tar -C / -xvzf "${packageLocation}/install.tar.gz" "etc/"
```

This finds the Store Appx (UWP) package, queries its location on the drive, and then extracts the files in `etc/` from the `install.tar.gz` roots back into your `/etc`.

Exit WSL, do a `wsl --shutdown`, and restart.

You should now be `root` again (instead of just UID 0), and in your default (presumably `bash`) shell.

##### Recreate your default user

```
useradd --user-group --groups  adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,netdev --shell /usr/bin/bash --password $(read -sp Password: pw ; echo $pw | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) <username>
```

##### Recreate configuration files for manually installed packages

This is a challenge, and the part that makes me agree with others that you are best off deleting the instance and starting over.

You basically need to re-run the install for each previously installed package (the list is stored in `/var`, so it's still intact) and have it recreate any configuration files in `/etc` as well as any `postinst` script that modified it (e.g. group or user additions).

You can get a list of all manual package installations with:

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

And you can get a list of packages that placed files in `/etc` with:

```
dpkg -V
```

But the order of reinstallation involves the dependencies, and your changes of getting everything set back up "just right" are extremely slim, IMHO.

Failure on either this step or the next would leave your installation in an unstable state, and still require a full reinstall anyway.

##### Manual configurations

At this point, if there were any changes that you can recall manually making that would have impacted `/etc`, try to recreate these.